404 NOT_FOUND error when deploying my NextJS MERN stack webapp to Vercel
Currently trying to deploy my web app to Vercel and no matter how much tutorials I watch or read, it still shows 404 NOT_FOUND when I deploy my web app to vercel.
My vercel.json file
{
  "version": 2,
  "name": "infinite-sia",
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "server/server.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/api/(.*)",
      "dest": "server/server.js"
    },
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "app/$1"
    }
  ]
}

My server.js code
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express")
const server = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
server.use(express.json())
const cors = require('cors')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const mongoURL = process.env.MONGO_URL;

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const corsOptions = {
    origin: isProduction ? 'https://infinite-erp.vercel.app' : 'http://localhost:3000',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
    credentials: true
  };

server.use(cors(corsOptions));

// MongoDB Connection
mongoose.connect(mongoURL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  }).then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to database");
  }).catch(e => {
    console.error("Error connecting to database:", e);
  });

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server Started on port ${PORT}`);
});

//My CRUD endpoints....

if (isProduction) {
    server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'out')));
  
    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'app', 'out', 'index.html'));
    });
  }
  
module.exports = server;

My file structure

I tried different methods like exporting my express app
module.exports = server;
Deploying my backend and frontend separately which resulted to some error with CORS and adjusting the vercel.json multiple times. The only time it "worked" was when I deployed my web app for the first time without the vercel.json and adjusting the urls. It showed the front end but it couldn't fetch data from the backend (my database).
